# Typehint a setter that allows null

Tags: php, type-hinting

In my entity I have a property that is a value object.

```
class Meeting
{
    /** @var MeetingStatus */
    private $status

    /**
     * @param MeetingStatus|null $status
     */
    public function setStatus(MeetingStatus $status = null)
    {
        $this->status = $status ?: new MeetingStatus(MeetingStatus::DRAFT);
    }
}
```

The only way I see to both typehint and to allow null is by setting null as default parameter value. But it seems very weird to allow a setter without a required parameter.

```
$meeting->setStatus(); // wut?
```

Does anyone have an elegant solution for this?

Comment: According to the official documentation, giving $status the default value of null is the way to go. Semantically, there is no difference between calling setStatus() and setStatus(null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `public $status` to `MeetingStatus::DRAFT`

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->status = MeetingStatus::DRAFT;
}
```

and don't call setter if you have it as NULL.

*OR*

Always set meeting status. You can set it to `MeetingStatus::UNDEFINED` where `const UNDEFINED = null;`

Answer (score 1):

You may set default value in constructor, almost like in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37023085/206729):

```
private $status;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->status = new MeetingStatus(MeetingStatus::DRAFT);
}

public function setStatus(MeetingStatus $status)
{
    $this->status = $status;
}
```

Now you doesn't need to make member public or allow null in setStatus()

Comment: Your solution works if OP wants $status to be immutable